# How to use bind in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React, and I saw that one common practice is to bind the functions in the constructor, which I also want to use. Though, I don't exactly get how bind works for functions that take parameters. For example, I have something like this:

```
class MyClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onListClicked = this.onListClicked.bind(this);
    }

    onListClicked(id) {
        // performs some action
    }

    render() {
      return (
        // partially removed for brevity, value of myId comes from a loop
        <ListItem onClick={ () => this.onListClicked(myId) } />
      );
    }
}
```

Now this works in my case, but I'm not taking advantage of `bind` fully. If I change the `ListItem` to `<ListItem onClick={this.onListClicked} />` it doesn't work as expected. This would have worked if `onListClicked` didn't accept any parameters. But, in this case I don't know how to take advantage of bind. Any ideas?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it didn't change anything. I don't think the name is the problem here. I need to somehow pass the parameter to the function, in this case the `myId`.

Comment: You need to pass the handler to the `ListItem` component as a prop, and then from there u can call it.

Comment: And from where `myId` is coming from?

Comment: @Prakashsharma inside the `render` method I have something like: `this.state.currentlyDisplayed.map(category => ...)` and then `myId` in my case is something like `category.categoryId`. So, it comes from using the `map` function on an array.

Comment: @typos In that case the way you are using (i.e. `onClick={ () => this.onListClicked(myId) }`) is perfectly fine. What problem are you facing? If you want to pass the argument then this way is correct.

Comment: @Prakashsharma I just assumed I can somehow get rid of the arrow function, and use it purely as `onClick={this.onListClicked}`.

Comment: @typos Gave an answer to your problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question has little to do with binding, and is really about how React handles callback props.

Every React event-listener function is passed an instance of React's [`SyntheticEvent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) object as its first parameter.

`onClick={this.onListClicked}` will call the `onListClicked` function and pass it one parameter: the `SyntheticEvent` object provided by React.

`onClick={this.onListClicked.bind(this)}` is the same as the last example.  `onListClicked.bind()` returns a wrapped version of `onListClicked` with its [context object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) set to `this` (which in your case is your React component because that's what `this` is set to when you do the binding).  This wrapped version of your function still only receives one parameter: a `SyntheticEvent` object.

`onClick={(e) => this.onListClicked(myId)}` will call the anonymous fat-arrow function and pass it one parameter: a `SyntheticEvent` object, because the anonymous fat-arrow function is the callback and all callbacks get that parameter.  This anonymous fat-arrow function ignores its own parameters, and calls `this.onListClicked` with the value of `myId`.

`onClick={() => this.onListClicked(myId)}` is the same as the last example, except we are ignoring the `SyntheticEvent` because we don't care about it.

`onClick={this.onListClicked.bind(this, myId)}`, as suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46266518/635678), will wrap and call the `onListClicked` function and pass it TWO parameters: the first is `myId` (since `bind` is injecting `myId` as a parameter as well as setting the context to `this`) and the second is a `SyntheticEvent` object.

So:  depending on what exactly you are doing inside of `onListClicked`, you may or may not need to bind it to your React component (or to some other context).  Do you actually need variables and functions defined inside a particular object?  Then bind your callback context to that object, and call `this.foo` or `this.bar` all you need.  But if you don't need access to those sorts of things, there's no need to use `bind` just because it's there.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

`bind` function takes a context as its first argument and takes your original function arguments as the next set of arguments after `this`. The "binded" (excuse me for the horrendous grammar!) function that is returned has the same arguments "binded" to it so when you call it, it will be called with the same set of arguments that it was bound with.

So essentially a `<ListItem onClick={ () => this.onListClicked(myId) } />` should be replaced by a `<ListItem onClick={this.onListClicked.bind(this, myId)} />`

I, however, don't see a way for you to generate the function you need in the constructor itself since you won't have those arguments there to start with. You could loop over the array in the constructor itself and create those "binded" functions there only but that would be just a waste and a much elegant solution would be to use the above said method.

Read more about `bind` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

---